# JTable, cambiar que el getHeaderValue regrese un Object en lugar de un String

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy trabajando en crear un horario de citas.

Tengo un `JTable` donde la primer columna la lleno de forma "manual" con los horarios disponibles, y las demás columnas se agregan de forma dinámica, leyendo de la BD la tabla `Empleados`. Al utilizar el objeto `DefaultTableModel` y agregar cada columna, agrego un objeto tipo `Empleado` y por el `toString` de mi objeto imprimo el nombre del empleado como `Header` en cada columna.

[image: horariosjTable]

Estoy por implementar la funcionalidad de que al darle clic derecho en una celda, pueda agregar una cita para un cierto empleado en un cierto horario. 
Quisiera tomar el objeto `Empleado` de la columna seleccionada, y no únicamente el `String` del `HeaderValue`, es decir, cómo podría regresar todo el objeto `Empleado` que, previamente, agregué cuando creé la tabla, ya que necesito guardar el `IdEmpleado` y no únicamente el nombre. He intentado crear mi propia clase `TableColumn` o `DefaultTableModel`, pero no obtengo buen resultado.

Agrego código:

En esta función cargo los empleados y los agrego como columnas:

```
public void cargaColsEmp(DefaultTableModel dtm, JTable t){        
    ConnectMySql c = new ConnectMySql();

    Statement stmt;
    String query;
    ResultSet rs;

    int numEmp = 0;

    try {
        stmt = c.conn.createStatement();
        query = "select * from Empleados where Estatus = 1 order by IdEmpleado";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
            int idEmpleado = rs.getInt("IdEmpleado");
            String nombreEmpleado = rs.getString("NombreEmpleado");
            double sueldoBase = rs.getDouble("SueldoBase");
            double porcentajeServicio = rs.getDouble("PorcentajeServicio");
            int estatus = rs.getInt("Estatus");

            Empleados e = new Empleados(idEmpleado,nombreEmpleado,sueldoBase,porcentajeServicio,estatus);
            dtm.addColumn(e);
            numEmp++;
        }//close while
    }   
}
```

Con esto, tomo el horario y trato de tomar el objeto de la columna, pero solamente puedo tomar el `String` del nombre:

```
String hora = (String) horario_table.getValueAt(horario_table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
TableColumn emp = horario_table.getColumn(horario_table.getColumnName(horario_table.getSelectedColumn()));

System.out.println("Hora: " + hora);
System.out.println("Columna: " + emp.getHeaderValue());
```

Agregando `Class Empleados`:

```
public class Empleados implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "IdEmpleado")
    private Integer idEmpleado;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NombreEmpleado")
    private String nombreEmpleado;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SueldoBase")
    private double sueldoBase;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PorcentajeServicio")
    private double porcentajeServicio;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Estatus")
    private int estatus;

    public Empleados() {
    }

    public Empleados(Integer idEmpleado) {
        this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
    }

    public Empleados(Integer idEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, double sueldoBase, double porcentajeServicio, int estatus) {
        this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
        this.nombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado;
        this.sueldoBase = sueldoBase;
        this.porcentajeServicio = porcentajeServicio;
        this.estatus = estatus;
    }
}
```

// Más todos los getters y setters para las variables.

Al correr ejecutar la linea: 
System.out.println("Columna: " + emp.getHeaderValue().getClass().getName());

Me regresa que la clase es "String", es aquí lo que me interesaría modificar, que la el objecto que regresa fuera, en mi caso, de tipo Empleados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías mostrar tu código para facilitar las cosas.

Comment: Vale, agrego parte de mi código

Comment: Agrega declaración y constructor de la clase `Empleados`.

Comment: Vale, agrego class Empleados ...

Comment: Parece que ya lo tienes, confirma: `System.out.println("Columna: " + emp.getHeaderValue().getClass().getName());`.

Comment: Que tal Sal, gracias, te muestro el resultado y te comento...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buen día, he podido hacer lo que necesitaba y quiero dejar mi solución por si a alguien le sirve para futuros proyectos.

1) Cree mi propia class para añadir un DefaultTableModel a mi tabla. La clase llamada "MyDefTableModel" extiende de la clase "DefaultTableModel". Aquí cree un metodo llamado "getColEmp", que me regresa un tipo Object. Esta función es muy similar a la función "getColumName" pero como está te devuelve un String fue que tuve que crear la nueva y no solamente sobreescribirla. Anexo código:

public class MyDefTableModel extends DefaultTableModel 
{    public MyDefTableModel(){
        super();
    }

```
public Object getColEmp(int column) {
    Object id = null;
    // This test is to cover the case when
    // getColumnCount has been subclassed by mistake ...
    if (column < columnIdentifiers.size() && (column >= 0)) {
        id = columnIdentifiers.elementAt(column);
    }

    return (id == null) ? getColEmp(column) : id;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
    return false;
}
```

}//close class

Teniendo esto, ya solamente utilizo esta nueva clase con mi tabla y utilizo el objecto de esta nueva clase para tomar el objecto persona que está en los headers de las columnas de mi tabla. Anexo código:

String hora = (String) horario_table.getValueAt(horario_table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
Empleados empleado = (Empleados) mydtm.getColEmp(horario_table.getSelectedColumn());

y ahora ya con el obejto empleado puedo accesar a los atributos de la clase.

Gracias a la comunidad, si gustan pueden dar por resuelta la pregunta.

Saludos !!